# Json Syntax Error on Session Expire

Tags: php, slim

I'm working with Slim Framework and I would like to redirect the user to the login page if the user has lost his session but I'm always getting a SyntaxError : Unexpected token < at position 0.

My session validation code in php is this:

```
private function _validaSessao() {
    $user = $this->userData['IdUser'];
    if(null === $user || trim($user) == '') {
        header("Location: http://192.168.0.9/", true, 301);
        die();
     }
}
```

I've tried that and all the following:

```
header('refresh:5;url=http://192.168.0.9/');
echo '<script>window.location.href = "http://192.168.0.9/";</script>';
return('<script>window.location.href = "http://192.168.0.9/";</script>');
echo json_encode('<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://192.168.0.9/">');
```

I've tried them all and I'm always getting

```
200 ---- SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

The only piece of code that worked for me was:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'SemSessao' => true
));
```

But the above code makes me checking on every single call on JavaScript and I would like a solution that PHP will redirect me. This way I wouldn't need to keep checking on every single JS call (which are a lot) and each time a php object was instanciated it would check for session and redirect the user without the use of JS.

## Update 1 - Include JS code (lovely downvotes everywhere :D)

```
getDadosPlaneamento: function() {
    var req = {Rota: '/planeamento/getDados/AUTO'};
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.when(App.gajax(req)).done(function(d) {
        On.Planeamentos     = d.Planeamentos;
        dfd.resolve();
    });
    return dfd.promise();
},
```

The above code is what refers to my php route and then:

```
$onapp->get('/planeamento/getDados/:tipo/', function($tipo) {
    if ($tipo == 'AUTO') {
        $P = new MongoApi\Planeamento();
        $ret = array(
            $P->getAllMongo();
        );
    }
echo json_encode($ret);
});
```

And when I do `$P = new MongoApi\Planeamento();` I check if the user has a valid session on the constructor using _validaSessao();

Comment: @wayneOS thanks, that one is not working aswell anyway...

Comment: Sorry i mistook that. you need to set your `header()` on top of your scritp to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server cannot redirect a client from an AJAX call. The AJAX call is a background HTTP request. Whether that HTTP requests gets redirected or not is irrelevant to the browser. The browser will return the request response to the AJAX client, and if that response is "your request has been redirected" then that's that. Again, a redirect doesn't redirect "the browser", it redirects *the HTTP request*. Or more precisely speaking, it tells the HTTP client that it should retry its request somewhere else; nothing more.

If your AJAX requests can fail due to a session timeout and whenever that happens you want to present the user with a login page, you will have to do that client side. In order to not repeat that same code every time, you make a function/object/service out of that. E.g. something along the lines of:

```
function makeAJAXRequest(url, data) {
    return fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status == 403) {
                window.location = '/login';
                throw new Error('Forbidden');
            } else {
                return response;
            }
        });
}
```

Here the server is expected to respond with a `403 Forbidden` status code for unauthorised requests. If you make all your AJAX requests through this function, it will automatically handle that case by redirecting to the login page.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, someone actually explained this to me in a clear way! And didn't downvote my topic hurray! I'll upvote your answer man ;)

Answer (score -1):

Remeber that [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) must be called before any output is generated. you can use [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [op_end_flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) to avoid output previous to your header.

```
ob_start ();
header ("Location: http://192.168.0.9/", true, 301);
ob_end_flush ();
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that aswel, but the thing is that JS is expecting a JSON response. When debugging using chrome dev tools using this solution the page is loaded, but the browser does not update what it is showing!

Comment: what JS? you were asking about redirecting with php. could you update your question, then i will happy to help you ;)